# Коллбек функция не возвращает значение

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

```
    function load(data_field) {
      var response_object = {}; //объект в который нужно вернуть значение из коллбека
      chrome.storage.sync.get(data_field, function (result) {
          response_object = result; // сохраняем в объект результат 
      });
      return response_object; // доожен содержать объект, хотябы с одним полем
    }
```

Почему response_object не изменяется??????

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.get асинхронная? Если так, то ваш `return response_object` отработает раньше, чем `response_object` получит значение

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вариант с коллбэком

```
function load(data_field, callback) {
  var response_object = {}; //объект в который нужно вернуть значение из коллбека
  chrome.storage.sync.get(data_field, function (result) {
      response_object = result; // сохраняем в объект результат
      callback(response_object);
  });
}
```

Comment: Да, с коллбэком стало работать, но только в консоли. Если использовать эту функцию в контексте расширения, то возвращается пустая строка

Comment: @Александр, ищите ошибку в логике. Можно проверить данную функцию, запустив ее сразу после записи считываемой переменной.

Answer (score -2):

Может быть что-то с `result`?

Попробуй return `result` или даже

```
if(typeof result === 'object')
{
  response_object = result; // сохраняем в объект результат 
     return response_object; 
}
else
{
  alert('Error - typeof result = ' + typeof result + ' value = ' + result);
}
```

Если `result` по плану текст или номер то для присвоения объекту параметра нужно юзать `Object.result = result; return Object`

Comment: C result все нормально, потому что в консоль внутри коллбека он выводит нормальный результат